# Regex to match phone and fax numbers for WebHarvy

Tags: regex, webharvy

Sample text

```
5950 S Willow Dr Ste 304 
 Greenwood Village, CO 80111
 P (123) 456-7890
 F (123) 456-7890
 Get Directions
```

Tried the following but it grabbed the first line of the address as well

```
(.*)(?=(\n.*){2}$)
```

Also tried

```
P\s(\(\d{3})\)\s\d+-\d+
```

but it doesn't work in WebHarvy even though it works on RegexStorm

Looking for an expression to match the phone and fax numbers from it. I would be using the expression in WebHarvy

https://www.webharvy.com/articles/regex.html

Thanks

Comment: Ok, but what is your question? How did you try to write the regular expression?

Comment: Sorry Juzraai - I have added more info to my question above. Kindly check. Thanks

Comment: Try `P\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d+-\d+)` or `\bP\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d+-\d+)`

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. Could you please tell me where I went wrong with the one I tried above (the second one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second pattern is almost what you need to do. With `P\s(\(\d{3})\)\s\d+-\d+`, you captured into Group 1 only `(\(\d{3})` part, while you need to capture the whole number.

I also suggest to restrict the context: either match `P` as a whole word, or as the first word on a line:

```
\bP\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d+-\d+)
```

or

```
(?m)^\s*P\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d+-\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%5Cs*P%5Cs%28%5C%28%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C%29%5Cs%5Cd%2B-%5Cd%2B%29&i=5950%20S%20Willow%20Dr%20Ste%20304%20%0D%0A%20Greenwood%20Village%2C%20CO%2080111%0D%0A%20P%20%28123%29%20456-7890%0D%0A%20F%20%28123%29%20456-7890%0D%0A%20Get%20Directions%20), and here is what you need to pay attention to there:

[image]

The `\b` part matches a word boundary (`\b`) and `(?m)^\s*` matches the start of a line (`(?m)` makes `^` match the start of a line) and then `\s*` matches 0+ whitespaces. You may change it to only match horizontal whitespaces by replacing the pattern with `[\p{Zs}\t]*`.